# Application-defined or object-defined error validation list

Tags: excel, vba

So i tried to copied my "TotalRange" and after it's pasted i tried to add new data validation list into one of the cells. It keep getting error on the Row 10.

```
Sub Order_AddTotals()
Dim LastRow As Long
With Sheet1
    LastRow = .Range("P8:Q999").Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("P8"), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row  'First Avail Row
    .Range("P" & LastRow + 2 & ":W" & LastRow + 5).Value = .Range("TotalRange").Value
    .Range("Q" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=Sum(T8:T" & LastRow & ")" 'Sub Total
    .Range("Q" & LastRow + 3).Formula = "=Q" & LastRow + 2 & "*TaxRate"
    .Range("T" & LastRow + 3).Formula = "=Q" & LastRow + 2 & "+Q" & LastRow + 3 & "-T" & LastRow + 2 'Total
    .Range("T" & LastRow + 4).Formula = "=Q" & LastRow + 4 & "-T" & LastRow + 3
    .Range("Q" & LastRow + 5).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Payment_Method" 'This part is the problem
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(At least) two things could cause that:

a) The formula is invalid. Do you have a named range `Payment_Method` in your sheet? Can you set this manually in your sheet?

b) The cell has already a validation. Even if it is exactly the same, you need to remove it first. When setting the validation via code, always issue a `Delete` first (it's okay even if the cell has no validation at that moment).

```
With .Range("Q" & LastRow + 5).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Payment_Method" 
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently i didn't issue a delete first.